# Can an Influence Disc be moved to an adjacent hex if there is no other influenced hex adjacent to that target hex?

Tags: eclipse

The rules state the requirements of moving from and to hexes, but don't clarify whether the action of moving a disc "from" a hex invalidates that hex as an influenced neighbor.

Put another way, can I move a disc from one hex to a neighboring hex if there is no **other** influenced (or ship-resident) hex next to that destination hex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you move the influence disk, pick up the disk from the hex and place according to the rules i.e.

- to a hex that does not contain an Influence Disc or an enemy
  Ship and is adjacent to a hex where you have a disc
  or a Ship.
- to a hex where only you have a Ship.

The disk cannot move across the explored space on it's own

> Q: Using the Influence action, I can move an Influence Disc from a hex to its neighbor through a Wormhole connection. May I move the Disc that created this connection in the first place?
>   A: No. If you move the disc, there is no longer a connection.

Source: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/711246/eclipse-official-faq